# Determining the final state of the gas in the tank

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, air, adiabatic

Suppose there is air of mass m1 in an insulated tank at temperature T1 and pressure P1.

0.25m1 of air is released through a valve attached to the tank. Find the final temperature, T2 and pressure P2?

I know its a transient state process and has to use control volume equations. But am having my doubts on how to solve it.

Edit : 
 Equation that I used :
[image]

subscripts meaning-
e-exit
i-inlet
1-initial state of CV
2-final state of CV

I dont know how to calculate the enthalpy of air.

Comment: Can you give us some idea of how you have attempted to solve this problem so far? How about writing down some of the key equations governing the system?

Comment: I tried to use the first law equation for control volume undergoing a transient process.

Comment: @tok3rat0r No it is not a repeat. PV^γ=Constant is for control mass. Here the problem that I am asking deals with control volume.

Comment: Ah, you're right: i saw 'insulated tank' and immediately thought of an adiabatic process. Comment deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your old friend $PV^\gamma=k$ for the expansion.  Imagine putting a divider sheet across the tank, with $0.75m_1$ on the side away from the outlet and $0.25m_1$ on the side toward the outlet.  As the gas is released, the sheet moves until it is against the wall with the outlet. If the divider is massless, the pressure is the same on both sides, and no work is done.  You are expanding the volume from $3/4$ of the tank to all of it.

Comment: As I have earlier mentioned in the comment, PV^γ=k works for control mass undergoing reversible process. And the system is well defined homogeneously at all points in the control mass. But the question that I have put forth involves control volume and a transient process.

Comment: My divider changed it to a control mass.  The mass in the volume away from the vent is constant.  The process inside the tank is reversible-you could make the divider a piston and recompress the control mass.  The escape out the vent is irreversible, but we are not concerned with that gas.

Comment: Nice thinking. Couldn't get it before. This involves a intuitive model and simpler math. Thanks